# how to recover mysql password in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Mysql version - mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper.

I had forgotten my password and tried many commands online.Also the problem is that grant tables command not working in my terminal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://askubuntu.com .

Answer (score 15):

```
~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS \n \l

~$ aptitude show mysql-server |grep Version
Version: 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
```

In file: /etc/mysql/debian.cnf are two important lines:

```
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = <unique password>
```

Use that user and password to login to mysql:
Once logged in as debian-sys-maint you can:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

Comment: By itself, this doesn't work. There must be another step needed. `ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: This worked, for some reason the standard procedure wasn't letting me login

Comment: That's amazing I just used those credentials in phpmyadmin changed the password for root. Thanks!

Comment: Time saver, you are genius :)

Answer (score 2):

The following adjustments works for my setup:

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
$ sudo chown mysql: /var/run/mysqld
$ sudo kill -9 $(sudo cat /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Stop the Database Server.
    `sudo systemctl stop mysql`

2) Restarting the Database Server Without Permission Checking. For this following command
    `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`

3) Connect to the database as the root user
    `mysql -u root`

4) Change the Root Password

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

5) Restart the database server narmally

```
sudo kill `cat /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

sudo systemctl start mysql
```

Now login with new password in database:
`mysql -u root -p`

Or you can follow the following link:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password

Comment: Step 2) gives me `mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.`  Are we supposed to create that directory?

Answer (score 0):

I had tried all the approaches but didn't work for me. The following approach worked. I am hopeful that it will work on different versions of ubuntu.

1. OS info:

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

2. First, stop MySQL service using command

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
```

3. Other commands didn't work and here how I start the MySQL server without any permission-checking. To do so, run:

```
// open the mysql systemd configuration file your default text editor. 
// In my case, it is nano editor.
sudo systemctl edit mysql

// Add the following 3 lines
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

4. Reload systemd configuration using command:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

5. Start MySQL service

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

6. Now, connect to MySQL server as root user without password:

```
sudo mysql -u root
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'add-newpassword-here';
```

7. Revert the modified systemd configuration

```
sudo systemctl revert mysql
```

You are all Done.